# Is there an algorithm to extract values in duets from an array and operate over them?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have an array like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And I want to get items in duets like this:

- 1,2

  - Do some operations...
- 2,3

  - Do some operations...
- 3,4

  - Do some operations...
- 4,5

  - Do some operations...
- 5,6

  - Do some operations...
- 6,7

  - Do some operations...
- 7,8

  - Do some operations...
- 8,9

  - Do some operations...

Please suggest an elegant way to achieve this using Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].each_cons 2 do |a,b|
  p [a,b]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You want [Enumerable#each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001515):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].each_cons(2){|pair| p pair}
```